# Where is ADF IActivityLogger logger stored?

Tags: azure, logging, azure-data-factory, custom-activity

I am currently Working on Azure Data Factory Pipeline.
I am putting _logger.write("My error content.") on my .net custom activity.

However, I cannot find where the log would be stored.
I looked on internet and could not figure out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ADF logs are stored in `adfjobs` container in your Azure Storage account.

Each slice output is assigned an unique *Run ID*. You can find this ID in Azure portal when you click on slice details in your DataFactory *Diagram* or *Monitor and Manage* pane. This *Run ID* is also the name of the folder you're looking for in `adfjobs` container. In that folder, you have `Logs` and `Runtime` subfolders and in `Logs`, you will find both system logs and your user logs.

Comment: Thank you! I could find  user defined log file, with other system files too!